# Deleting a branch locally then push vs delete locally then use Github's own 'Delete branch' feature

Tags: git, github

I created a new branch in my local repo, them pushed it to my `Github` account. Used it and now I want to remove it. To delete it locally I can go:

```
git branch -d test-branch
```

To delete this branch in `Github` I can do:

```
git push origin --delete test-branch
```

But `Github` has its own *Delete Branch* feature. Is there any difference between using the last command above and using `Github`'s own function? Do I have to pull something if I delete the branch from within `Github`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two features are identical and you don't have to pull anything even if you delete your branch from within Github.